# Use ajax to get string from database, split it in half, and convert it to speech

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, text-to-speech

I'm trying to use ajax to get a string from my database, echo the full string, and then split the string in half, and convert it to speech. I have done every steps right except one step. I got the full string from my database, and successfully split it in half. This is the last step where I'm having trouble:

**Part Where I'm Having Trouble**

```
echo "
<script type = 'text/javascript'>

var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('$partOfString');
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

</script>
";

?>
```

**test1.php**

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 

   function ajaxPass(gotoUrl,input,output) {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: gotoUrl,
           data: { input : input },
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
           document.getElementById( output ).innerHTML = data;
           }

      });

}

</script>

<input type = "button" value = "Click me" onclick = "ajaxPass('test2.php','Hello','output')"> 
<div id = 'output'> </div>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php

$text = $_POST['input'];

//Use $text to get a string from database

echo $text; //echo the string we get from database
$partOfString //split the string in half and store in partOfString

echo "
<script type = 'text/javascript'>

var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('$partOfString');
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

</script>
";

?>
```

Comment: Can you define "having trouble"? What is the desired behavior? What is the actual behavior?

Comment: It's not reading into speech. It works while it's not after an ajax call though. When it's test2 is just a page without the ajax function calling it.

Comment: Ajax can retrieve your data without loading. So why pass it in another page?

Comment: Have you loaded jquery?